Use of CSRF_COOKIE_MASKED setting while upgrading django version to 4.1?
I am upgrading django version from 4.0 to 4.1, and in the release notes it says:

CsrfViewMiddleware no longer masks the CSRF cookie like it does the CSRF token in the DOM.

And it gives a setting as well called CSRF_COOKIE_MASKED for transition:

The new CSRF_COOKIE_MASKED transitional setting allows specifying whether to mask the CSRF cookie.

My question is how to decide whether to use this CSRF_COOKIE_MASKED setting or not while upgrading to 4.1?
Also, what kind of testing can I do to verify such changes?

this answer your question ?
And how the docs said if you If you are upgrading multiple instances of the same project to Django 4.1, you must set CSRF_COOKIE_MASKED to True during the transition, to enable compatibility with older versions of Django.

You can test this way:
def cookie_masked(self):
    self.client = Client()
    response = self.client.get('/your_url')
    csrf_cookie = response.cookies.get('csrftoken')
    self.assertEqual(csrf_cookie.value, 'expected_value')

Hope this help you
